# XML still empty?

Tags: c#, xml

This may be a very stupid question, but I can't seem to get this thing working.
I'm trying to form an XML with the following structure, and be able to add additional data into it at any point in time, as well as read the data.
Right now all I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sessions />
```

What I want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sessions>
<session date="14.10.2016" time="17:15" amount="3">
<folder>C:\\Users</folder>
<folder>C:\\Test</folder>
<folder>C:\\Asgbsf\\Aleksei</folder>
</session>
<sessions />
```

My C# code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        createXML();
        Console.WriteLine("Test XML");

        folderList.Add("C:\\Users");
        folderList.Add("C:\\Test");
        folderList.Add("C:\\Asgbsf\\Aleksei");
        XML();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static List<String> folderList = new List<String>();


    private static string generateRandom(int min, int max)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return rnd.Next(min, max).ToString();
    }

    public static string pathToXml = "test_aleksei2.xml";
    public static void createXML()
    {

        XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(pathToXml,   Encoding.UTF8); //Creating file
        textWritter.WriteStartDocument(); //XML header
        textWritter.WriteStartElement("sessions"); //XML head
        textWritter.WriteEndElement(); //end writing element
        textWritter.Close(); //close XmlTextWriter 


    }



    public static void XML()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("XML function being executed");
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); //using XmlDocument to  Read
        document.Load(pathToXml); //loading XML
        XmlNode element = document.CreateElement("session"); //parent element


        XmlAttribute date = document.CreateAttribute("date"); //creating attribute
        date.Value = "14.10.2016"; 
        element.Attributes.Append(date); //append attribute to element 

        XmlAttribute time = document.CreateAttribute("time"); 
        time.Value = generateRandom(0, 23) + ":" + generateRandom(1, 59);
        element.Attributes.Append(time);

        XmlAttribute amount = document.CreateAttribute("amount");
        amount.Value = generateRandom(1, 10);
        element.Attributes.Append(amount);


        XmlNode folder = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < folderList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folderList[i]+" - " + i + "/" + folderList.Count);
            folder = document.CreateElement("Folder");
            folder.InnerText = folderList[i];
            element.AppendChild(folder);
        }


        document.Save(pathToXml);

     }
```

Help please, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If I just c&p I might not even learn what's the issue here... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML method, you never append the `session` element to the document after you create it.  So, even though you create and add all those children to the element, none of it gets added to the document.

You need to add this line before you save the document:

```
document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(element);
```

Comment: Wow, perfect! Works as indented, although I cannot add additional elements, it all gets overwritten, but I guess I need to dig deeper. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Gosh, I'm dumb. I didn't remove the createXML() function, and it was re-creating the XML file... Lol